# Call Client On Database Change

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, comet

i am Creating messaging system in asp.net.
how can i call client on database change?
for example user's Page is open and another user sending message for that user.
how can Software notify User ?
is it right to call web-service every X seconds/minutes ?
any solution with jQuery / AJAX /Comet ?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [**Reverse AJAX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax)

See [**jQuery Comet Long Poll Implementation**](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/reverse-ajax)

Comment: is that comet? would you please introduce any jQuery Plugin Or sample?

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX/JQuery solution would be to create a timer polling the web service every X seconds/minutes.  [Example](http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/posts/jquery-periodicalupdater-ajax-polling/).

Answer (score 1):

thanks all answers :).

> Comet is a programming technique that enables web servers to send data
>   to the client without having any need
>   for the client to request it. It
>   allows creation of event-driven web
>   applications which are hosted in the
>   browser.
>   http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/